# C# FTDI Multithreaded Write

Tags: c#, multithreading, usb, ftdi

Using FTDI D2XX drivers to work with FTDI's USB to Serial and an embedded FT232RL, running into an issue where the FTDI Write is Failing with FT_IO_ERROR after 10+ hours of operation, and subsequently the port dies.  WES7, C#, .net 4.0.

```
        FTDI.FT_STATUS status = m_FtdiSerialPort.Write(data, (uint)numBytesToWrite, ref numBytesWritten);
```

Attempts to re-open the port return FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED.

```
        FTDI.FT_STATUS status = m_FtdiSerialPort.OpenBySerialNumber(SerialNumber);
```

I have read in documentation that this is due to a multi-threaded application's main thread conflicting with the thread writing the FTDI data.  I have been unable to find further documentation of a multi-threaded write, although I have set the timeouts.

```
        m_FtdiSerialPort = new FTDI();
        ...   
        m_FtdiSerialPort.SetBaudRate(9600);
        m_FtdiSerialPort.SetDataCharacteristics(FTDI.FT_DATA_BITS.FT_BITS_8, FTDI.FT_STOP_BITS.FT_STOP_BITS_1, FTDI.FT_PARITY.FT_PARITY_NONE);
        m_FtdiSerialPort.SetFlowControl(FTDI.FT_FLOW_CONTROL.FT_FLOW_NONE, 0, 0);
        m_FtdiSerialPort.SetTimeouts(5000, 100);
```

Has anybody had similar experience with D2XX and FTDI's C# interfaces?  Is there a preferred method to write data in multi-threaded apps with FTDI?  Is there a method to reset the FTDI port that does not involve resetting the whole driver stack?

Code is appreciated!

Please Help me, Thank You!

Comment: It's working with 10 hours of operation time. Have you been able debug to see what's causing the the IO error? Or have any logs?

The documentation is assuming that you're doing multithreading but I don't see where you're doing any multithreaded operations. If it really is a multithreading error then create a class to handle all your FTDI requests and async/await from your main thread

Comment: @Zakk Diaz the device driver for the USB to Serial Converter appears to lose its VID/PID/Serial Number as if it were disconnected.  If the application is sitting there passively writing and reading USB data, it can do it forever.  When all the functionality is being used in the APP including all libraries this happens.  I can not directly source level debug, because one of the libraries that is used detects debuggers and shuts operations down.  Will take the advice on FTDI Comms thread.

Comment: I have a feeling it doesn't have to do with your code. Could it possibly be that the machine is disabling the device? Putting it to sleep to save power or something. If you restart the application right after it disconnects does it start normally?

Comment: @ZakkDiaz thanks for that.  I have made sure through the settings that the device is not being turned off by power saving.  If I restart my application the condition persists, I have to either reset the embedded FT232RL device on the other end or reboot the PC.  That is why I thought perhaps if I could cancel the data, close the port, reset the device driver, cycle port and reopen it that might do it.  I do not have a good sample FTDI code to do that on WES7 because like WinCE FTDI.CyclePort does not work on WES7.

Comment: I worked a lot with FT232H chip. When there were problems which I could not trace inside the application, it helped to checke the windows EventViewer --> Windows Logs --> Application and/or System categories. Sometimes it can help you to reveal nasty low level issues with hardware communication. But I don't now if you have access to it in wes7